# Java agregar if dentro de un for recorrer array

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, condiciones

Tengo el siguiente problema:
9)Dando por buena la estructura de la matriz descrita anteriormente
¿sabrías incluir un if dentro del bucle elegido en el ejercicio 8 para filtrar los gastos, por ejemplo, mostrando solo aquellos superiores a 50€?.

y el código que tengo es:

```
    String[][]  gastos = {{"Cafe","23/8/22","560"},{"Coca","20/8/22","300"},
            {"Empanadas","10/8/22","800"},{"Vino","15/8/22","700"}};


    Arrays.stream(gastos).forEach((i) -> {
    Arrays.stream(i).forEach((j) -> System.out.print(j + " "));
    System.out.println();
    });
```

el problema anterior era:
8- En esta ventana podemos ver el listado de gastos. Imaginemos que tales gastos se encuentran almacenados en una matriz donde se almacena el concepto, la fecha y la cantidad del gasto.
¿Qué bucle usarías para recorrer toda esa información y mostrarla?

Comment: "sabrías incluir un if dentro del bucle elegido en el ejercicio 8" ¿y cuál era el ejercicio? Agrega siempre el contexto necesario para comprender el problema en cuestión. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: Y cual es el problema??? agrega el if...

Comment: Hay una razón para guardar las informaciones de cada gasto como un generico String[] en lugar de utilizar una clase bien hecha "Gasto" y filtrar el Stream de Gasto[] por `getGasto() > 50`?

Comment: Soy nuevo en java y directamente me están dando ejercicios antes de aprender un poco mas la sintaxis y demas

Comment: si recién estas comenzando te recomendaría mostrar los datos en el ejercicio 8 usando un doble ciclo for, y aplicar solo uno en el ejercicio 9,ademas de realizar el cast de `String to int` en `gatos[indicex][2]` ya que ahi se encuentran los valores a los cuales debes aplicar la  condicional `if`